# Android SQLlite database initial index positioning

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

My Android app is successfully writing to a SQLlite database but is writing to a _id position of 0. Is there anyway I can adjust the initial write code to the database and not start at position / row 0? I'm using this method of testing to verify the position of the currently selected person from a spinner / dropdown to eventually delete the client.

I was able to test its place like so:

- `Cursor c = db.getClient(currentlySelected+1);` returns a successful test toast message of position 1 and I did this to verify the first position is or was 0.
- `Cursor c = db.getClient(currentlySelected);` crashes and DDMS reports a CursorIndexOutOfBounds error requesting a 0 with a 0 or something like that.

DB is a database adapter:

```
db.open();
long currentlySelected = contactList.getSelectedItemId(); //spinner populated from database
Cursor c = db.getClient(currentlySelected+1);
Toast.makeText(LookupReturn.this, 
"Cursor position: " + c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//db.deleteClient(currentlySelected);
c.close();
db.close();
```

-------------------------- THE PORTION BELOW WAS MY RESOLUTION ----------------------------

```
db.open();
                            long currentlySelected = contactList.getSelectedItemId()+1;
                            long currentlySelectedTemp = currentlySelected;  //holds initial position value when this value is removed from the main db
                            Cursor c = db.getClient(currentlySelected);
                            if(c.moveToFirst())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(LookupReturn.this, "Position: " + currentlySelected, //c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex("_id")),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                db.deleteClient(currentlySelected);
                                c.close();
                                db.close();

                                Toast.makeText(LookupReturn.this, "Deleted",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                deleteClient.setChecked(false);
                            }

                            //remove from secondary db
                            DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

                            SQLiteDatabase s = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
                            s.execSQL("DELETE FROM returnvisits WHERE _id = " + currentlySelectedTemp);
```

s.close();

Comment: How looks `getClient()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android db starts writing from _id `1`. For reading values from cursor, you need to do

```
c.moveToNext();
```

after executing

```
 Cursor c = db.getClient(currentlySelected+1);
```

Then you can use the cursor to get values.

Comment: Was it helpful for you?

Comment: @Stefano_Munarini yes it was thank you! It got pointed in the right direction to how I eventually solved it above.

Comment: @Stefano_Munarini sorry about that still getting used to this site properly. If you can rep up the question? ( I think thats how it works :/ ).

Comment: "Rep up" is for user in the future that see your question and mark it as interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `c.moveToNext();` or `c.moveToPosition(positionIndexHere);` to move to the next position, or a particular position in the database.(c is the cursor variable)